# How to style MUI TreeItem label?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I'm trying to customize a [`TreeView`](https://mui.com/components/tree-view/) by adding a border to each [`TreeItem`](https://mui.com/api/tree-item/).

Generally it works great, my current version looks like this:

[image: current view]

But I wish it looks was like that, and I have no idea how to style it:

[image]

So basically, I would like to surround only `TreeItem`'s label with `<div>`.
Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the `MuiTreeItem-label` class name when styling the `TreeItem`. For reference, see the list of all CSS global class names [here](https://mui.com/api/tree-item/#css).

```
import TreeItem, { treeItemClasses } from "@mui/lab/TreeItem";

const StyledTreeItem = styled(TreeItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .${treeItemClasses.label}`]: {
    border: "solid blue 1px",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    marginTop: 3,
    marginBottom: 3
  }
}));
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Other than the accepted solution you can also try using the `sx`prop, this might be helpful if you just want to customise 1-2 elements instead of every item, which would look something like this:

```
<TreeItem
  sx={{
       "& .MuiTreeItem-label": {
           fontSize: "1.5rem" 
        }
      }}
 />
```