# Styling nested MUI TreeItem not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview, react-typescript

I'm trying to implement a tree data structure with using [TreeView](https://mui.com/components/tree-view/#main-content).
Recently I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596143/how-to-style-mui-treeitem-label) about styling a [TreeItem](https://mui.com/components/tree-view/#heading-api).

I my case each [node](https://mui.com/components/tree-view/#heading-api) in the tree has it's own property saying whether it should be displayed as green or red.

```
interface OrganisationTreeItemProps extends TreeItemProps {
  shouldBeGreen: boolean;
}

const OrganisationTreeItem = styled(TreeItem, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop: PropertyKey) => prop !== "shouldBeGreen"
})<OrganisationTreeItemProps>(({ theme, shouldBeGreen }) => ({
  [`& .${treeItemClasses.label}`]: {
    .....
    color: shouldBeGreen ? "green" : "red", // the problem is here
    .....
  }
}));
```

Here's a *CodeSandbox*, that best describes the problem.

[image: Edit new]

How could I solve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here:
[LINK](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/30029)

> The problem is that the classes for the labels (both the green and
> red) have the same specificity. In scenarios where you have
> hierarchical structure, I would recommend using different classes and
> targeting them, for example `greenLabel` and `redLabel` class based on the
> prop. Here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-galileo-och9b?file=/src/App.tsx