# Material ui TreeItems change style conditionally based

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [TreeView](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/), [TreeItem](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tree-item/) of material ui.
I'm trying to style conditionally each node (selected, hover, focus).
actually what I'm trying to do is that only node that not disabledButton (props that come from outside) will be in right color.
only node that selectable will be in active color (expand node not means that node is selectable).
something like this example
[image]

I did this example, but the behavior is really weird, sometimes the "child-4" looks like the style of disabledButton even I sent the right props, maybe because it nested props, sometimes the other nested not get the right colors of the hover, focus and selected..
link for example (with colors)
[example with different colors](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rhv3gr-ucrykn?file=demo.tsx)

I want it to be in real colors also with the theme (active should be like blue color, hover gray) so I created this example.
[example with theme colors](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rhv3gr?file=demo.tsx)
sometimes it works as expected and sometimes is not.
I looked in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70125287/styling-nested-mui-treeitem-not-working-as-expected) but it's not like my example but there it uses in classes but I don't want to send this way

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Do you wish the following? 1. Active nodes are selected nodes and you want them to be in `main` theme color. Hover should be `secondary` color. 2. Expandable nodes cannot be active, they should just expand/collapse. 3. Expandable and leaf nodes can be disabled individually and cannot be active, selected or hovered over. 4. You don't want to use css classes?

Comment: umm, something like that. I want something like in the gif..  if I expand node, it not means it should be selected\active,only if I press on node it selected. in addition, there is some nodes with attribute disabledButton that I don't want them to be selected

Comment: maybe some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little while this is what I got. I tried to match the design of the gif as good as possible.

[image]

I used this `data` which I derived from the question. This example has one **disabled** node and **parent node** (`my-photo.jpg` and `zip` directory). The data array can be expanded endlessly if it matches `TreeData` type.

```
export type TreeData = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  disabledButton: boolean;
  children?: TreeData[];
};

const data: TreeData[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "My Web Site",
    disabledButton: false,
    children: [
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "images",
        disabledButton: false,
        children: [
          { id: "3", name: "logo.png", disabledButton: false },
          { id: "4", name: "body-back.png", disabledButton: false },
          { id: "5", name: "my-photo.jpg", disabledButton: true }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "6",
        name: "resources",
        disabledButton: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: "7",
            name: "pdf",
            disabledButton: false,
            children: [
              { id: "8", name: "brochure.pdf", disabledButton: false },
              { id: "9", name: "prices.pdf", disabledButton: false }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "10",
            name: "zip",
            disabledButton: true,
            children: [{ id: "11", name: "test.zip", disabledButton: false }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The `CustomTreeView` consists of `CustomTreeItem` that again makes use of `CustomContent`.
`CustomContent` is used to handle all events and to display another icon (folder) next to the `expandIcon`.

In the `CustomTreeItem` I set the width to **fit-content** to not select the whole row, but to match the example from the gif:

```
const CustomTreeItem = (props: TreeItemProps) => (
  <TreeItem
    ContentComponent={CustomContent}
    {...props}
    sx={{
      width: "fit-content",
      ".MuiTreeItem-content": {
        py: "2px",
        width: "fit-content"
      }
    }}
  />
);
```

The interesting part is the styling of the `CustomTreeView` and its usage.
I have packed the classes into objects, which can be overwritten easily. The theming happens in the styles class which is in `styles/Styles.ts`.

```
// Styles.ts
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const getMuiTheme = () =>
  createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#2160dd"
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#d3d3d3"
      }
    }
  });

// CustomTreeView.tsx
const classes = {
  focused: {
    bgcolor: "transparent",
    py: "1px",
    px: "7px",
    border: `1px solid ${getMuiTheme().palette.secondary.main}`
  },
  selected: {
    bgcolor: getMuiTheme().palette.primary.main,
    color: "white"
  }
};

const CustomTreeView = ({ data }: { data: TreeData[] }) => {
  return (
    <Box mt={2} ml={2} bgcolor="white" width="300px">
      <ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <TreeView
          defaultCollapseIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
          defaultExpandIcon={<ArrowRightIcon />}
          defaultEndIcon={<InsertDriveFile />}
          sx={{
            ".MuiTreeItem-root": {
              ".Mui-focused:not(.Mui-selected)": classes.focused,
              ".Mui-selected, .Mui-focused.Mui-selected, .Mui-selected:hover":
                classes.selected
            }
          }}
        >
          {renderTreeData(data)}
        </TreeView>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

To render arbitrarily nested data we make use of the **recursive** method `renderTreeData`. This way the `data array` can be expanded endlessly as long as it matches `TreeData` type.

```
export const renderTreeData = (data: TreeData[]) => {
  return data.map((item) => (
    <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
      {item.children ? (
        <CustomTreeItem
          nodeId={item.id}
          label={item.name}
          disabled={item.disabledButton}
          icon={<FolderOutlined />}
        >
          {renderTreeData(item.children)}
        </CustomTreeItem>
      ) : (
        <CustomTreeItem
          nodeId={item.id}
          label={item.name}
          disabled={item.disabledButton}
          icon={getFileIcon(item.name)}
        />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
};
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit nervous-babycat-jlbqnq]